# C# Application Executable will not run on any other device

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have devoloped a C# Application to search a certain directory, read in any files containing a certain string, and then compare those to a database and do various things with said information. I need to upload the project\exectuable to another machine where it will contantly run on a timer, however Every time I try to open the exectuable on any other device I get the windows error, the GradeUpdate (my project name) has stopped working. I created the project in Visual Studio 2013, and only have a few references out of the ordinary which are as follow, and I made sure these references are in my release folder that I copy over to the device which I need the program to run on.

```
MySqlData.dll
MySqlWeb.dll
```

I recreated the project from scratch thinking it may be a naming issue, but this did not make a difference. In addition a C# application written in Studio 2010 works on the machine that I am trying to access, however the 2013 application I wrote does not. I believe there may be some local file not included in the project folder that it access's on my local computer, but that is my best guess, any and all suggestions would be very welcome!

Comment: the infamous `works on the machine` this is a common mistake that beginners make when learning to code.. just because it works on your machine will not guarantee that it will work on others I would first look at the properties of the .dll / assemblies and make sure that you have the `CopyLocal` property for the dll's set to `true` make sure that not only are you adding the assemblies in the using header section, but manually adding them to the reference node.. also make sure that the target machine has the same .net framework installed on their machine..

Comment: I would highly recommend adding so logging as well .. make sure that you have code that catches and handles exceptions properly .. as your question stands it currently leaves all of us in the dark

Comment: @MethodMan Thank you so much! I never knew about the CopyLocal property and all of my references were set to false, I changed this over and it worked immediatly. Again thank you so much, been stuck on this for quite some time.

Comment: believe it or not this is a common mistake that most programmers do.. I am glad that I was able to see the problem and or issue immediately without wasting any of your valuable time.. I will put it down as an answer and you can accept it as the working fix if you like thanks again

Answer (score -2, accepted):

`the infamous works on the machine this is a common mistake that beginners make when learning to code.. just because it works on your machine will not guarantee that it will work on others I would first look at the properties of the .dll / assemblies and make sure that you have the CopyLocal property for the dll's set to true make sure that not only are you adding the assemblies in the using header section, but manually adding them to the reference node.. also make sure that the target machine has the same .net framework installed on their machine.`

Answer (score -1):

Could it be that the machine doesn't have the version of the .NET runtime you're targeting? If you're using Visual Studio 2013, your app may be targeting .NET 4.5. Can you make sure the target machine has the .NET 4.5 runtime installed?

Comment: Another possibility could be the folder that it's trying to access doesn't exist on the target machine.

Comment: this should be a commentd definitely not an answer especially when you are trying to answer a question with a question...

Comment: The target machine has .NET 4.0 but under the solution properties I also have it set to 4.0 in Visual Studio

Comment: check to make sure that you have the `dll's` properly copied over into the directory of the target machine where the application launches.. also make sure you do not have any `HARD CODED File Paths` because what's on your machine is not necessarily on their machine.. if I were you I would create a dependency folder and add all 3rd party dll there then remove current reference and re-add them pointing to the dependency folder